# How do I get the averages of duplicate values in a postgresql column?

Tags: postgresql

I have a postgresql table that looks like this

```
Division     Rate
   a           7
   b           3
   c          4
   a          5
   b          2
   a          1
```

I want to return a table that looks like this

```
Division       Average
  a               3.5
  b              1.6
  c               5
```

Is there any way for me to do that? I can't seem to come up for the logic for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select Division,avg(Rate) from your_table group by  Division;
```